# ArcGIS Enterprise Sites 10.8.1: Problem with Layer Description in Feature Service

Tags: arcgis-portal, arcgis-enterprise, arcgis-hub

I have published a number of Feature Layers (hosted) and want to make them accessible to the web via ArcGIS Enterprise Sites. I published via ArcGIS Pro 2.5.2, the data originally comes out of a SDE database and has been copied to the Datastore during the process.

Obviously, I want to add a nice description to every dataset that explains the data and also supports the search.
While I have been able to get the description to work in the portal (automated with Python) (see below)...

[image]

.... this is not the same what I get as description in  ArcGIS Enterprise Sites (see below):

[image]

When I click on the Layer in Portal, I see the following:

[image]

Obviously Sites shows the description from the layer and not the one in Portal. Is this on purpose?
If yes, how is it possible to change the description?
I have tried that programmatically as below:

```
search_result = gis.content.search(query=...)
for i in search_result:
   for f in i.layers:
   f.properties.description = i.description
```

and also:

```
for i in search_result:
      update_dict = {'Description': i.description}
      subitem = FeatureLayerCollection.fromitem(i)
      subitem.manager.update_definition(update_dict)
```

This seems to work, but it does not get saved. I have also tried "updateDefinition" via REST, but it did not get saved either. Any idea what I can do to make it work? Making the layer editable does not change anything. However, I can change other settings like the capabilities (Query, Extract) with the same approach as above and it gets saved.

Do I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Hmmmm. It works as you expect for ArcGIS.com Open Data (eg. https://open.ottawa.ca/datasets/parks-and-greenspace uses a mapservice and you can see the Item description vs Service Layer description difference). I wonder if its a bug in Enterprise Sites? Or perhaps some caching is going on and it hasn't refreshed the Site Item to see the updated description.

Comment: Since it has not changed over the weekend, my guess is that it is a bug. I will check with ESRI Support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion with ESRI Support, this behavior has been identified being a bug and is now registered as #BUG-000134505: The item description is unable to be changed in the ArcGIS Enterprise site when the corresponding feature service sublayer already contains a description.

Current Status: "In Product Plan", so it will hopefully be resolved with one of the next patches/updates

**Finally I also found a workaround:**
When deleting the description on the [CIM level of the layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/de/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm), it works after being published to ArcGIS Enterprise.

```
cim_version = 'V2'
lyr_definition = layer.getDefinition(cim_version)
lyr_definition.description = ""
layer.setDefinition(lyr_definition)
```